# pandas converts float64 to int

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the dtype of a column (`A`) in a `dataframe` from `float64` to `int`,

```
df['A'].astype(numpy.int64)
```

but after that, `A` still gets `float64` as dtype. I am wondering how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

It seems your output is not assign back, so need:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(numpy.int64)
```

If `NaNs` use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for convert them to `int`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(0).astype(numpy.int64)
```

Or remove all rows with `NaN`s in `A` column by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.dropna('A')
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(numpy.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have NaN values, then Pandas can't convert it to `int`.

But most probably you just didn't assign result back to `A` column (as @jezrael has already said).

If you would try to convert NaN's to integer you would get the following exception:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan,4]})

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
     A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  4.0

In [6]: df['A'] = df['A'].astype(np.int64)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```